# grid item span won't span more than 1 column

Tags: css, css-grid

The orange box won't span more than one column no matter what I set the "grid-column" to be.

Why is that?

I have tried the following: combinations:  (It's the `.hr-3` item)

`grid-column: 6 / span 9;`
`grid-column: 6 / 9;`
`grid-column: 2 / 7;`
`grid-column: 2 / span 9;`

I triple checked that I am targeting the right item.

Nothing seems to work..

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Teko');
html, body {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#a {
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background: rgb(250,250,250);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1px auto repeat(6, 2fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto repeat(9,1fr);
  //transform: rotate(-45deg);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
.item {
  //background: rgba(100,100,0,0.02);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.item-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
.item-2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 3px;

}
.item-3 {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
   writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
.item-4 {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  
}
.hr-1 {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / span 3;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.hr-2 {
  grid-column: 6 / 7;
  grid-row: 1 / span 8;
  border-left: 25px solid red;
 
}
.hr-3 {
  grid-column: 6 / span 9;  // <------- DOESN'T WORK?
  grid-row: 6/8;
  border: 25px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div class="item item-1"><b>John</b></div>
  <div class="item item-2"><b>A</b>lexander</div>
  <hr class="hr-1"/>
  <div class="item item-3"><b>B</b>lue</div>
  <div class="item item-4"><b>Peterson</b></div>
  <div class="item item-5"></div>
  <hr class="hr-2"/>
  <hr class="hr-3"/>
  <hr class="hr-4"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hr` has a default margin set that is creating the issue. Make them equal to `0`.

The default margin is set to `auto` so it's aligning your item (an empty one) inside the track which make you think your element isn't spaning the needed columns. What you will see in all the case is the `50px` border you made (left+right)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Teko');
html, body {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#a {
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background: rgb(250,250,250);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1px auto repeat(6, 2fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto repeat(9,1fr);
  //transform: rotate(-45deg);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
.item {
  //background: rgba(100,100,0,0.02);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.item-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
.item-2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 3px;

}
.item-3 {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
   writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
.item-4 {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  
}
.hr-1 {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / span 3;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.hr-2 {
  grid-column: 6 / 7;
  grid-row: 1 / span 8;
  border-left: 25px solid red;
 
}
.hr-3 {
  grid-column: 6 / span 9;
  grid-row: 6/8;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}

hr {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div class="item item-1"><b>John</b></div>
  <div class="item item-2"><b>A</b>lexander</div>
  <hr class="hr-1"/>
  <div class="item item-3"><b>B</b>lue</div>
  <div class="item item-4"><b>Peterson</b></div>
  <div class="item item-5"></div>
  <hr class="hr-2"/>
  <hr class="hr-3"/>
  <hr class="hr-4"/>
</div>
```

Here is what you can see using the dev tools and by keeping the default margin:

[image]

You can see that the element is taking `9` column and `2` rows and the margin is centering everything inside.

Comment: It's though being a newbie, how am I supposed to know that or figure that out by myself?

Comment: @xingZì by asking and someone else who already faced this you will tell you and now you know it ;)  ... but you can inspect the element to see the default style which isn't trivial because you also have to know that margin is causing the alignment of an empty element

Comment: For some reason, Firefox doesn't show the default hr styling https://gyazo.com/f099639576400d2411e195d2794fae0d (left is chrome, right is firefox). Weird ..

Comment: @xingZì check this : https://briangrinstead.com/blog/inspect-user-agent-styles-in-firefox-devtools/